# Website not showing properly on Safari 5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I have a website which I designed. Its appearing perfectly on all browsers including newer versions of Safari.

However the only issue I am facing is in Safari 5.1 & 6.

My website URL is - http://samiakamar.com

My issues are in **bold**, if someone can help I will be really grateful.

**The home page sliding images are not showing**

[![Slider images not showing][1]][1]

& on this page - http://samiakamar.com/lookbook-inner-new.html

**Images are showing all stretched.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. The link will not become invalid. Also, I am not sure what part of code you want me to include.

Comment: You can't **guarantee** that the link won't become invalid...that's why we ask for code,

Comment: The link itself may not become invalid, but if you change anything on the website, this question will become worthless and answers will become unreliable. What if someone says "the problem is with the div on line 440", but there is no div on line 440 any more, because you're experimenting? That is why you need to inlcude the code in the question. Preferably as a snippet, that we can test.

Comment: I got it! 

I will paste the code. Thanks ever so much :)

Answer (score 0):

So we are facing 2 problems on Safari 5.1 & 6. All other browsers & newer versions for safari is showing perfect. So here is some code which we are using in our site:

1. For Slide we have used BX Slider:

```html
<div class="bxslider">
         <ul>
             <li style="background:url(images/slide1.jpg) 50% 50% / cover no-repeat"></li>
                <li style="background:url(images/slide2.jpg) 50% 50% / cover no-repeat"></li>
                <li style="background:url(images/slide3.jpg) 50% 50% / cover no-repeat"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

We can't paste the complete code as we don't even know whats the problem & why is it not showing on safari older versions

Here is the css link for slider: http://www.samiakamar.com/css/jquery.bxslider.css

Here is the js file link for slider: http://www.samiakamar.com/js/jquery.bxslider.js

This is the inline js code which we have used:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    setliHeight();
 $(window).resize(function(e) {
        setliHeight();
    });
 $('.bxslider ul').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  auto: true,
  controls : false
 }); 
});
function setliHeight() {
 $('.bxslider ul li').height($(window).height())
}
</script>
```

2. For lookbook page we have used a big coding for it therefore I can't insert that all here its better if someone check for the issue on the link lookbook-inner-new.html & let me know the issue so i will paste that old & newer code for future reference for other's help.

However the only issue I am facing is in Safari 5.1 & 6.

Hope it will help you guys to provide me a better solution.

Thanks,

Comment: So there are to pages which are getting problems:
1. http://www.samiakamar.com/
2. http://www.samiakamar.com/lookbook-inner-new.html